# How to view Adobe Launch data from Android app?

Tags: android, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics, adobe-launch

I want to see analytics in my android application, but am struggling to set Adobe Launch and Analytics up.

I have Mobile Core and Analytics set up in the app itself. And it isn't producing any errors on run.

```
MobileCore.setApplication(this)
        MobileCore.setLogLevel(LoggingMode.DEBUG)
        try {
            MobileServices.registerExtension()
            Analytics.registerExtension()
            Lifecycle.registerExtension()
            MobileCore.start { MobileCore.configureWithAppID("app-id-here") }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Log
        }
```

And have created the property in Adobe Launch adding the relevant extensions needed, setting up environments and publishing a library. I now have a library published. But have no idea how to view the data gathered from the app? Am I miss understanding what Launch is? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Once registeration is done you can able to see the logs in App logs "AdobeExperienceSDK" but to see the actual event you need to login on AEP dashboard portal.

For setup and instruction please visit below official url from Adobe Launch

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/launch-learn/implementing-in-mobile-android-apps-with-launch/configure-launch/launch-install-the-mobile-sdk.html?lang=en#prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but if you're asking how to see an aggregation of the data you sent to Adobe, your request contains the address of the repo where you're sending your info. You need to log into Adobe Analytics to see what you sent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the events to track the screen views. Example:

```
Analytics.trackState("Screen Name", null);
```

The oficial documentation:

https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/mobile-services/android/analytics-android/states.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://aep-sdks.gitbook.io/docs/using-mobile-extensions/adobe-experience-platform-assurance , which can let you see Adobe Launch console/debugging notes in the Adobe Griffon interface. A bit overkill for a one-time thing, but if you're going to be spending a lot of time withLaunch in your app, it might be worth setting up.